# Xamarin: Table_Section.GetEnumerator() items

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Workout_Cell class that inherits from ViewCell.
Each new Workout_Cell is dynamically displayed below the previous on a button click event.

I'm trying to iterate through the custom cells on the ContentPage by doing:

```
IEnumerator<Cell> Cell_List = this.Table_Section.GetEnumerator();
```

I was hoping to retrieve a list of Workout_Cells, but instead when I use:

```
Cell_List.Current.GetType();
```

the types in the list are "Xamarin.Forms.ViewCell", therefore I cannot access the methods in my custom Workout_Cell.

Am I missing a cast or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UITableVIew always returns UIViewCells, so you haven't done anything wrong. Your right in your OP, you simply need to recast the cell to your type.

For example:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
      IEnumerator<Cell> Cell_List = this.Table_Section.GetEnumerator();
      Workout_Cell firstCell = Cell_List.FirstOrDefault() as Workout_Cell

      firstCell.AccessMyMethodsWoopWoop();
}
```

Give that a shot and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I cast it using "as" and VS intelisense now shows my Workout_Cell's methods but when I try calling them a NullReferenceException is thrown. They were not null prior to the cast.

Comment: Are you definately adding of type Workout_Cells into the table to begin with? it's unusual for them to not cast correctly when you pull them out again. =)

Comment: You are correct. I had a different custom cell inside my Table_Section that was also being cast. Thank you sir.